# How to move a folder containing aliases to another machine without breaking the aliases?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, alias

I've got a large folder of music with lots of aliases to tunes that are spread throughout subfolders of the main tunes folder. For example I might keep the original files sorted by artist, and then have a folder for a genre with a bunch of aliases to tunes (or folders of tunes) for that genre, like a playlist.

Now that I've got a new laptop how can I transfer the whole folder without breaking the aliases?

I tried using the symbolic link options of rsync but that doesn't seem to work with OS X aliases.

BTW I'm not interested in replacing the aliases with a copy of the original, I really want to keep the aliases :)

Is this something Time Machine can help with?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Aliases are not the same as symlinks](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFileSystem/Articles/Aliases.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002288-BAJBEHFB).

Symlinks just point to a path (relative or absolute).
Aliases first track the file's unique ID and then the path.

Since there are two pieces of information stored in an alias - they are more robust and will follow a file that's moved based on the unique ID. The downside is that the unique ID is based on the file system so copying the file elsewhere mints a new ID so the alias doesn’t map to the new location by design and implementation (currently at least).

Finder (or the very powerful `ditto`) are your best bets for moving aliases intact. Worst case you could use disk utility to make an image of a folder that contains everything needed as a subfolder and then move that to preserve the relative locations of the files and isolate the effects of a short name change (/Users/whatever) in case you wish to change that. Once the original mac is disconnected from the new mac - the aliases will reconnect as desired to location of the files on the new mac.

Answer (score 2):

I believe aliases will be handled correctly if copied through the finder, even to external media.  If you are doing it through `rsync` you will probably have issues.

References:

- [Forum Posting](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=117581)
- [Script to possibly convert Aliases to Symlinks](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20061201041424401)